# How to unscrew this square screw?

Tags: screws, drill, screwdriver

I have this screw that looks square and I have many of them to unscrew

I wonder if there is a tool that I can attach to my drill driver to unscrew them

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those bits do come in some of the larger bit sets as well.

Comment: @SolarMike what do they called?

Comment: They are known as square drive, also as Robertson.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson_screw

Comment: Most stores that sell tools will also have them as singles or packs of five or ten.  Do not need to buy a bit set when you only want that type and size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are screwdriver bits made to put in your drill in different sizes of square drive.

Comment: what does it called?

Comment: Just do a search on "Square drive bit."

Answer (score 1):

They are called square drives.  You can get them in combination of male and females.

Okay, I hope this helps.

Take care.

[image: Square bit drives]

Comment: You can also get them in regular hex-bit fittings.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that we’re looking at socket-sized square drives. Much more common is normal Robertson #2, and less so, #3.